# Where can I get a CAD model for the Moto X

Tags: moto-x

I am attempting to make my own 3D printed case for my phone. I need either very specific dimensions or a CAD model of it.

I've searched around but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Other than the fact that Moto X runs Android, I don't see how this question has anything to do with Android itself or its usage.

Comment: Week where the heck else would I go to get this question answered?

Comment: Have you tried contacting Motorola directly?

Comment: I was just about to if no one had any ideas

Comment: @PitaJ it may have been better to ask this on Blender using the [3D-printing](http://blender.stackexchange.com/tags/3d-printing/) tag. Just my opinion though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, one is available from Motorola [here](https://www.motorola.com/on/demandware.static/Sites-Motorola_US-Site/-/en_US/v1392847049240/webgl/geometry/motox_120613_3.dae), posted by Reddit user troub ([source](http://www.reddit.com/r/MotoX/comments/1yf5iq/anyone_have_a_3d_model_of_the_moto_x/)). It is a `.dae` file but can be converted using Autodesk FBX Converter (see [www.cadstudio.cz/download](http://www.cadstudio.cz/download) or [www.autodesk.com/fbx](http://www.autodesk.com/products/fbx/overview)). Alternatively, it is posted [here](http://www.thingiverse.com/thing:256551) on Thingiverse as a `.stl` file.